# MongoDB aggregation of multiple collections with $lookup with CosmosDB (Mongo API Enabled)

Tags: mongodb-query, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Firstly let me note, I am aware the data modelling is questionable here in a non-relational DB. But it is inherited and we are attempting a tactical solution at this point.

We have 3 collections; collectionA, collectionB and collectionC. These have relationships of CollectionA is one-to-many to CollectionB and collectionB is one-to-many to collectionC. The child document holds a ref to the parent in all cases.

Now we have a single use case requiring us to retrieve an aggregate of all 3 in a performant manner. But we are getting differing results with our solution against a CosmosDB instance and a MongoDB test container (closest likeness).

Our attempt to do this as MongoDB API novices is through an aggregation pipeline consisting of 2 stages of $lookup. Importantly, we are using CosmosDB with Mongo API enabled, which has limited support for the actual Mongo API.

Attempting the following aggregation pipeline against CosmosDB actually gives us the result we'd hoped:

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collectionB",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "CollectionBId",
      as: "collectionBList",
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collectionC",
      localField: "collectionBList._id",
      foreignField: "collectionCId",
      as: "collectionBList.collectionCList",
    },
  },
]
```

Result sample doc:

```
{
  _id: ...,
  collectionBList: [
    {
      ...
      collectionCList: [...]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, if we were to attempt the same with a mongo:4.2.0 test container we get a different result:

```
{
  _id: ...,
  collectionBList: {
      collectionCList: [...]
  }
}
```

**Note** `collectionBList` is an object.

Looking at MongoDB documentation for $lookup aggregation stage, it states "If the specified name already exists in the input document, the existing field is overwritten.", which I guess explains why the input document attribute `collectionBList` is overwritten for the second stage. But it appears CosmosDB behaves differently.

Part of my question is, have we interpreted this correctly and it is a known difference?

But my main question is, how would you achieve this aggregation with MongoDB aggregation stages?

Many thanks for your input!

Comment: This is not valid using MongoDB API as it does not support x-collection operations. Suggest using MongoDB vCore which will allow for this.  Details on the differences between the two types and when to use which is here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/choose-model

Comment: Thanks for your response @MarkBrown. I have to admit this has confused me quite a bit, I can't seem to see where it suggests x-collection use of aggregate command is not supported with CosmosDB Mongo API support. Referring also to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/feature-support-42. Let alone the fact in my development environment I am successfully using these features and getting the results i'd hoped. My only issue (apologies if question is poorly phrased) was the difference in behaviour running the same aggregation against an actual MongoDB instance.

Comment: I don't know what your dev environment is so unclear there.  The difference is not called out on that page but on the one I linked to. Specifically, vCore supports this, "Your workload has more long-running queries, complex aggregation pipelines, distributed transactions, joins, etc."  Mongo API is built on top of the Cosmos NoSQL API. This architecture is designed for extremely high throughput. Trade-off is no distributed transactions or operations of any kind.  Hope that helps.